# Importing products from directory dump structure

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following directory structure of my database dump (total of: 18,042,482 products):

```
/home/nataliya/dump/10xxxxx/100xxxx/1000006/
/home/nataliya/dump/10xxxxx/100xxxx/1000007/
...
```

Where `1000006` and `1000007` are the product's `id`.

Each folder contains:

```
description.txt (text)
details.csv (name, oldprice, price)
images.csv (url, size)
```

How do I import them into MySQL, using PHP, as following:

```
id, name, oldprice, price, description (table `products`)
product_id, url, size (table `images`)
```

I apologize in advance if the question is not relative to this website, and thank everyone who wish to help me.

---

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I'm asking only for a guidance, not for a full code example. Just the proper functions of PHP, which will make it with a good performance, since I'm talking about a directory with more than 30 million files.

---

**EDIT:** Here's what I've done for now:

```
<?php
function ArrayCSV($file) {
    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');

    while (!feof($fh) ) {
        $result[] = fgetcsv($fh, 1024);
    }

    fclose($fh);

    return $result[1];
}

$products = array();
$images = array();

foreach(scandir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dump/') as $dir_global) {
    if($dir_global != '.' && $dir_global != '..' && $dir_global != '.DS_Store') {
        foreach(scandir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dump/' . $dir_global) as $dir_local) {
            if($dir_local != '.' && $dir_local != '..' && $dir_local != '.DS_Store') {
                foreach(scandir(dirname(__FILE__) . '/dump/' . $dir_global . '/' . $dir_local) as $id) {
                    if($id != '.' && $id != '..' && $id != '.DS_Store') {
                        $dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/dump/' . $dir_global . '/' . $dir_local . '/' . $id;

                        $product = ArrayCSV($dir . '/details.csv');
                        $image = ArrayCSV($dir . '/images.csv');

                        $products[] = array(
                            'id' => $id,
                            'name' => $product[0],
                            'oldprice' => $product[1],
                            'price' => $product[2],
                            'description' => file_get_contents($dir . '/description.txt')
                        );

                        $images[] = array(
                            'product_id' => $id,
                            'url' => $image[0],
                            'size' => $image[1]
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

try {
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=application", 'root', '');
    $DBH->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    //
}

foreach($products as $product) {
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO products (id, name, oldprice, price, description) VALUES (:id, :name, :oldprice, :price, :description)");
    $STH->execute($product);
}

foreach($images as $image) {
    $STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO images (product_id, url, size) VALUES (:product_id, :url, :size)");
    $STH->execute($image);
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** Make a start on this yourself, if you have specific issues on the way we are more than willing to help. But we dont write code from a spec unless there is money involved

Comment: @RiggsFolly How's about whipping out your *magic* lamp there Smokey? Seems like that's what the OP's expecting ;)

Comment: I have to add, you will never get working app with 18M+ products on this level of knowledge. I suggest you to start with "hello world" app and keep going up to level where you do not need to ask, because even you get simple answer to "how to import 100 products of this structure" it won't work with 18M.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Importing large csv into mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932729/importing-large-csv-into-mysql-database)

Comment: You might be right there Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Reloecc, actually, I don't think we know each-other, so it's pretty strange to talk about my knowledge. I've passed the `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>` about 10 years ago. I haven't worked with that amount of files until now, so that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, actually, each CSV is about 1kb, so... The problem here is the amount of files to index.

Comment: So start simple with 20 products. 30million is just going to take longer. Write the script as a PHP CLI script so you dont have timeout issues. I would also suggest adding some restartability to the script so if one file causes you issues, you dont have to run it all from the start again

Comment: @Nataliya fine, ok.. as you see the first answer, I am not the only one who didn't get your question ;) So the main problem is count of files, I'll try to help you. Is this a one-time import, or the regulary one?

Comment: See if this Q&A helps http://stackoverflow.com/q/32368298/ it uses PDO and has a few answers in there that may be of help. It's the closest I could find.

Comment: You are a real gent Ralph @Fred-ii-

Comment: what can I say Smokey @RiggsFolly *I aims to please* ;-)

Comment: Well guys, I've added my code, it actually saves the output to an array, but you'll get the idea. The final step is to import it using PHP-PDO. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest familiarizing yourself with the following function [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) , [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and finally, all the [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions of PHP as they would be the key to what you'd need to do here.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, I'm going to use PDO's functions, but isn't there a better way than `scandir()`? I'm worried about the performance, it has thousands of folders.

Comment: Are you using linux ? can you please post the content from 2 Products from each file, to see if there is a header and if the fields are escaped

Comment: I'll post the output later when I'm at the office, but basically, I'm with OS X (Unix). Fields are comma separated, I think they were double " separated. It's an easy thing to fix, my main concern is the performance of this script - what do you think, do I need to set everything in an array, and then import it, or import it while doing to foreach?

Comment: Why don't you run it from cli on your computer instead of the server? It would alleviate majority of the stress.

Comment: I'll do exactly that, yes. I'll try tonight and see what will happen. But I'll try with inserting the records on each `foreach()`.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest familiarizing yourself with the `explode` function